# Ubuntu - gpointing-device-settings looses after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Operating System in my Dell Lap (Inspiron 17 R).

Touch Pad Scolling is not working.

After a long search, suggestions were to use `gpointing-device-settings` in my command line and to enable vertical or horizontal scolling.

After configuration, the scrolling was enabled and it works fine.

The setting was lost on every reboot. Again, I have to do the same to enable.

Kindly suggest me.